# How to get a log data using CZKEM on VB6

Tags: vb6

I am a basic fingerprint programmer and I really don't know how to get a data using component CZKEM on VB 6..

Here's my code, and I have an error using it.

```
Dim dwEnrollNumber As Long
Dim dwVerifyMode As Long
Dim dwInOutMode As Long
Dim timeStr As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lAddNew As Boolean

If CZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(vMachinenumber) Then
    i = 1
    CZKEM1.ReadAllUserID (vMachinenumber)

    While CZKEM1.GetGeneralLogDataStr(vMachinenumber, dwEnrollNumber, dwVerifyMode, dwInOutMode, timeStr)

        ListView1.ListItems.Add i, , dwEnrollNumber
        With ListView1.ListItems(i)
            .SubItems(1) = IIf(IsNull(timeStr), “”, timeStr)
            .SubItems(2) = IIf(IsNull(vMachinenumber), “”, vMachinenumber)
            .SubItems(3) = IIf(IsNull(dwVerifyMode), “”, IIf(dwVerifyMode = 1, “Fingerprint”, “Password”))
            DoEvents
        End With

        Dim d_TimeStr As Date
        d_TimeStr = CDate(Left(Right(Left(timeStr, 10), 2) & “ - ” & Mid(Left(timeStr, 10), 6, 2) & “ - ” & Left(Left(timeStr, 10), 4) & ” & ” & Right(Trim(timeStr), 8), Len(Right(Left(timeStr, 10), 2) & “ - ” & Mid(Left(timeStr, 10), 6, 2) & “ - ” & Left(Left(timeStr, 10), 4) & ” & ” & Right(Trim(timeStr), 8))))

        ListView1.ListItems.Add i, , dwEnrollNumber
        With ListView1.ListItems(i)
            .SubItems(1) = IIf(IsNull(timeStr), “”, timeStr)
            .SubItems(2) = IIf(IsNull(vMachinenumber), “”, vMachinenumber)
            .SubItems(3) = IIf(IsNull(dwVerifyMode), “”, IIf(dwVerifyMode = 1, “Fingerprint”, “Password”))
            DoEvents
        End With

        ListView1.Refresh
    Wend
End If
```

The error says : "Invalid property value"
Anyone please help me to solve this problem... :(

Comment: I removed the VB.NET tag - VB6 and VB.NET are **not** the same thing.

Comment: Which line gets the error? And, have you copied your code from a Word document? Those quote characters will not be valid in VB6. `“ - ”` should be `" "` and `“”` should be `""`

Comment: on .Subitems(1) = IIf(IsNull(timeStr), "", timeStr)

it says : "Invalid property value"

Answer (score 0):

This answer may serve as an alternative:

1. Check your finger print machine: Is it a TFT (with color lcd screen) or not> For TFT machines (you can check it with: `IsTFTMachine (dwMachineNumber)` syntax) you must use `CZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogDataStr(vMachinenumber, dwEnro......`
2. Be sure to check each given parameter because there is a different type of variable in `dwEnrollNumber`.  Specifically, on the TFT machine it is a `string` and on a non TFT-machine it is a `long`. This may be the cause of why your code gave the error message.